# Problems in codification - unicode vs. utf-8 in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, python-idle, pyyaml

Well, my python script is supposed to open all utf-8 yaml files in a directory and show the content to the user. But, there are words with graphic accent, words in French, such as présenter, which is shown like this: u"pr\xe9senter. I need it to be shown properly to the user.

Here is my code:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob("data/*.yaml") 

def read_yaml_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        try:
            print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)

for file in files:
    read_yaml_file(file)
```

I already tried to use the import from `__future__`, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Unicode in 2.x is painful.  If you can, use current python 3, in which text is unicode, printed without a 'u' prefix, instead of bytes, which is now printed *with* a 'b' prefix.

```
>>> print(u"pr\xe9senter")  # 3.8
'présenter'
```

You also need a system console/terminal or IDE that displays glyphs for the codepoints in your yaml files.

If you are a masochist or otherwise stuck on 2.7, use sys.stdout.write().  Note that you must explicitly write '\n's.

```
>>> import sys; sys.stdout.write(u"pr\xe9senter\n")  # 2.7
présenter
```

This question is not really about IDLE.  However, the above lines work in both standard interactive Python on Windows 10 and in IDLE.  IDLE uses tkinter which uses tcl/tk.  Tk itself can handle all Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) characters (the first 64K), but only those.  Which BMP characters it can display depends on your OS and its current fonts.